# Why can't Cloud run service (next.js) connect to another Cloud run service (node.js) through Direct VPC egress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless, vpn, google-cloud-run, google-vpc

I can't seem to send traffic from one cloud run service to another although I have setup a Direct egress VPC connection.

I am currently running 2 cloud services (**client** and **server**).

**server** is configured to only allow internal traffic through a Privacy Service Connect service (**psc**).

The **psc** exposes an endpoint in a **consumer** vpc which is reachable at **10.0.0.2** and publishes a service in a separate **producer** vpc connected to an internal load balancer (**ilb**) that directs traffic to **server**.

**client's** ingress control is set to allow all traffic because it is a public web app. Direct VPC egress with **consumer** vpc is enabled on **client**.

Lastly I created a DNS A record within a private zone that maps **server's** ***run.app** url to **psc's** consumer ip address **10.0.0.2**.

Each time **client** makes a request to server using its run.app url, a CORS error is raised.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://test-development-enterprise-api-ummzxs4jpa-ez.a.run.app/api/auth/passwordless' from origin 'https://psc-consumer-ummzxs4jpa-ez.a.run.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

The weird part is I can successfully make requests to **server** by sshing into a dummy vm I spawn in consumer's network.

```
ify@psc-consumer-2:~$ curl -k https://test-development-enterprise-api-ummzxs4jpa-ez.a.run.app/api/health
{"message":"Healthy Services","uptime":"5:3:46"}
```

Any idea what could be the issue here? I am happy to changing my approach if need be.

---

Below is a network topology that largely reflects my implementation.

[image: network diagram]

Apologies in advance if something does not make sense because i am pretty new to cloud networking.

Comment: You are not testing the same thing. CURL does not perform pre-flight request that cause CORS issue from your browser. Handle correctly CORS and it should work!

Comment: I set configured CORS to accept '*' on my server but still receiving the same error. I've also temporarily installed some chrome extension to by pass CORS which fixed CORS issue however I get this 404 `https://test-development-enterprise-api-ummzxs4jpa-ez.a.run.app/api/health 404 (Not Found)`. I went further and deployed a new demo cloud run service and pointed my **ILB** to it but still received the same 404. Is this [architecture](https://postimg.cc/sBRCQLCG) possible between a client and a server? in my case service **A** will be a public web app whilst service **B** is an internal.

Comment: Just to be sure to understand correctly the architecture, could you add a diagram at your question?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I don't see any blocker, except a not well managed CORS on your server side. However, I have a design question: why do you have this design? Will you share the service B across multiple project? Or do you try to solve something else?

Comment: Service B (server) will only serve Service A (client). I followed this google guide [Receive requests from other Cloud Run services, App Engine, and Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/private-networking?authuser=1&_ga=2.74805329.-2118526279.1700831345#from-other-services). My goal is to restrict access to Service B, ensuring it is not accessible via the internet. I am happy to adopt a different approach if you dont mind sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257041/discussion-between-remedy-man-and-guillaume-blaquiere).

Comment: You can directly reach service B from Service A making the ingress internal for the service B and the direct VPC access on the service A. No DNS or PSC required for that. At least for this use case!

Comment: I tried the above approach but still no access. I have recreated the issue in a sample project, are you okay for me to add you to the project so you can take a look?

Comment: Sure, add me as a viewer role. Here my email: guillaume.blaquiere@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks a lot for jumping on. I've added you as a `VIEWER` to **My First Project **. The design is exactly as you suggested, cloud run **service-a** attempting to talk to **service-b** using direct VPC egress through **client-server-test* vpc. To test this you can click on **service-a's** run.app link and paste in **service-b's** run.app link into the textfield and click on Next js logo to fire a network request.

Comment: It's easiest like that! I found the issue in your current configuration. You have to route ALL the traffic through the direct VPC. It's a "trap". Even if your service B is internal, the DNS is public, and the traffic is publicly routed to access it. That's why you must route the private and the public traffic to your VPC to have an authenticated traffic source and be able to access the service B

Comment: If I understood correctly, in **service-a** I have routed ALL routes through the VPC however it still isn't working.

Comment: How your service work? What should I set in the text field?

Comment: In the textfield you have to enter service-b’s run.app url —> https://service-b-q7zsa3awhq-ez.a.run.app and click the next js logo. If the request is successful a Hello message will appear below the textfield otherwise a 404 message will appear below the textfield. Additionally you can monitor your browser’s network

Comment: Ok got it. I understood the problem; It's a common mistake. In fact, you are loading data from your service A, CSS et JS to display your page in your browser. Then you try to reach the service B, FROM YOUR BROWSER. This last statement is the issue: when you have static code on your browser, you do not call the backed to perform the action. To solve that, you must have code running on the service A. And because you are on the service A, and not on your browser, the traffic will be routed to the VPC and be able to access the service B

Comment: Ok are you saying because the request is made from the browser it wont be able to reach **service-b**? How can i have code on service-a that will reach service-b? do you have any guide i could follow?

Comment: No special guide, but when you perform an action on your browser, the browser must call service A, which is public. The service A get the action, and perform a subcall to service B. Then get the response and forward it to your browser. It's a common pattern! Imagine your service B is a database API, it's the same thing! The browser never go to the database directly, but use service A as entry point to access the data in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance on this matter. I solved my comms issue by using **service-a's** Backend for Frontend to proxy requests to **service-b** thereby keeping said traffic INTERNAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting sir @guillaume and @remedy_man comments as answers from this post to help users from this concern. As per @guillaume the issue is loading data from service A, CSS et JS to display page in browser, then you try to reach service B, FROM BROWSER, because you do not call the backend when you have static code in your browser.

And what solve @remedy_man posted question is by using “service-a's Backend for Frontend to proxy requests to service-b”